Flutter - Build_runner doesn't generate files for my imported package
I created a small library to gather all my widgets in one place. Recently, I added the complete logic for my authentication page (Dio, Retrofit, Repository, Manager, etc.) to avoid recreating this page every time I want to create a new app.
However, in my authentication repository, for example, I'm using Retrofit, so I implemented something like this:
import "package:dio/dio.dart";
import "package:retrofit/retrofit.dart";

part "authentication_repository.g.dart";

@RestApi()
abstract class AuthenticationClient {
  factory AuthenticationClient(Dio dio) = _AuthenticationClient; 
  ....

So, I need to have the build_runner to create the .g.dart file.
I added it in the pubspec:
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1

  retrofit_generator: ">=7.0.0 <8.0.0"
  build_runner: 2.4.12
  json_serializable: 6.8.0
  custom_lint: 0.6.2

I pushed my library to Git and imported it into my main project.
The problem is that the build_runner in my main project can't generate the .g.dart files for my authrepo inside my library.

....authentication_repository.g.dart': File not found

How can I do that?
Thanks
(I have this error only when i'm starting my app)

it seems that the part and the file name should be the same:

change the part name(from authentication_repository to authentication_client):

import "package:dio/dio.dart";
import "package:retrofit/retrofit.dart";

part "authentication_client.g.dart"; // <- here


run command:

flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs


I posted one error of ~20 sorry, it's not a naming problem, it's more like my build runner in my main project can't generate files of my imported library

@Naografix build_runner won't generate .g file if the name is different

The file name is the same.
